# #N/A values when resizing Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

When I paste my array as such,

```
Set rngPaste = wksSkillsDist.Cells(iStartRow, iFirstColTotal)
    
rngPaste.Resize(UBound(arrTotals, 1), UBound(arrTotals, 2)) = arrTotals
```

I get `#N/A` values that are outside the bounds of my array. In my array, there are no `#N/A` values.

This is how I declare my Arrray

```
With wksSkillsDist
    
    'get last Column
    iColLastCategory = .Cells(iStartRow - 1, 2).End(xlToRight).Column
    
    'Create array which the indicies match the cells where values will go
    ReDim arrTotals(iStartRow To .Cells(iStartRow, iSkillCodeColumn).End(xlDown).Row, 2 To iColLastCategory) As Variant

End With
```

Here is an example of how items are added to arrTotals. Basically, check to see if certain strings match. If they match then I increment the corresponding spot in the array:

```
For iColumn = iFirstColPrimary To iLastColPrimary
    If szLevel = "Mastered" Then
        If InStr(1, wksSkillsDist.Cells(iHeaderRow - 1, iColumn), "Mastered", vbTextCompare) <> 0 And _
            StrComp(wksSkillsDist.Cells(iHeaderRow - 2, iColumn).Text, szELM) = 0 And bMasterMatch = False Then
                        
            iHeaderCol = iColumn
            bMasterMatch = True
            iTotal = iTotal + 1
                        
        End If
    ElseIf szLevel = "Developing" Then
        If InStr(1, wksSkillsDist.Cells(iHeaderRow - 1, iColumn), "Developing", vbTextCompare) <> 0 And _
            StrComp(wksSkillsDist.Cells(iHeaderRow - 2, iColumn).Text, szELM) = 0 And bMasterMatch = False Then
            
            iHeaderCol = iColumn
            bDevelopingMatch = True
            iTotal = iTotal + 1
        End If
    End If
Next iColumn
                
If bMasterMatch = True Or bPerformingMatch = True Or bDevelopingMatch = True Then
    If iTotal > 1 Then
        Debug.Print "ERROR"
    End If
    arrTotals(iSkillRow, iHeaderCol) = arrTotals(iSkillRow, iHeaderCol) + 1
End If
```

When I paste my values on the sheet using a Loop like such, I get no #N/A Values

```
'for first y coordinate to last y coordinate in array
For iRow = LBound(arrTotals, 1) To UBound(arrTotals, 1)
    
    'for first x coordinate to last x coordinate in array
    For iColumn = LBound(arrTotals, 2) To UBound(arrTotals, 2)
    
        'Add items to SkillDist worksheet
        wksSkillsDist.Cells(iRow, iColumn).Value = arrTotals(iRow, iColumn)
    
    Next iColumn

Next iRow
```

Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can you still show where you declare and populate `arrTotals` initially?

Comment: Also ensure that you clear all data from row `iStartRow` onwards. This will ensure that any `#N/A`  from your previous testing do not remain there :)

Comment: @BigBen Added where I declared arrTotals. It is not populated until there are matches.

I have also added a fact that when I populate the sheet using a loop there are no #N/A values

Comment: Have you used the locals window to check the dimensions of your array at sizing and before write out?

Comment: Could you share the complete code from `Sub` to `End Sub`, some source sample data, or at least a screenshot of the source so we can connect the dots? It's probably a simple mistake. When you get these error values, it usually means that the range is of a larger size than the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

### Range Size Larger Than Array Size (#N/A)

**A Quick Fix**

- Your array is not a **one-based** array i.e. its `'LBounds'` are not `1` but `iStartRow` and `2`.
- Your code is trying to fit the values of the array into a larger range a number of times i.e. e.g. assuming the number of columns is equal, if you're trying to fit an array of 3 rows into a range of 8 rows, it can't be done. If it were 6 or 9 rows, the array would have been written two or three times respectively.
- Of course, you want to fit it one time into the correct range. Study the material following this solution.

  ```
  rngPaste.Resize(UBound(arrTotals, 1) - LBound(arrTotals, 1) + 1, _
      UBound(arrTotals, 2) - LBound(arrTotals, 2) + 1) = arrTotals
  ```

**Any-Based**

- The number of rows (1st dimension) of any 2D array is calculated in the following way:

  ```
  Dim rCount as long: rCount = UBound(Data, 1) - LBound(Data, 1) + 1
  ```
- Similarly, the number of columns (2nd dimension) of any 2D array is calculated in the following way:

  ```
  Dim cCount as long: cCount = UBound(Data, 2) - LBound(Data, 2) + 1
  ```

**One-Based**

- Conveniently, to write the values of a range to a 2D **one-based** array, if there are at least two cells, one can simply do:

  ```
  Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Sheet1.Range("A1:J10")
  Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value
  ```
- Conveniently, using what we learned at the beginning, the number of rows in this 2D one-based array is equal to its `UBound` (since `LBound = 1`):

  ```
  Dim rCount As Long: rCount = Ubound(Data, 1) - 1 + 1 ' or...
  rCount = Ubound(Data, 1)
  ```
- Similarly, the number of columns in this 2D one-based array is equal to its `UBound` (since `LBound = 1`):

  ```
  Dim cCount As Long: cCount = Ubound(Data, 2) - 1 + 1 ' or...
  cCount = Ubound(Data, 2)
  ```

**A Small Study**

- Copy the following code into a standard module, e.g. `Module1`, of a new workbook. Play with (modify) the constants.
- Note that if you set `rStart` and `cStart` to `1`, the correct result will show in any case. This isn't covered because it would too much complicate the code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RangeVsArray()
    
    Const ProcName As String = "RangeVsArray"
    
    ' Imagine these are the results of you 'Range.End property' business.
    Const rStart As Long = 6
    Const rEnd As Long = 8
    Const cStart As Long = 2
    Const cEnd As Long = 14
    
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(rStart To rEnd, cStart To cEnd)
    ' ... i.e.
    'ReDim Data(6 To 8, 2 To 14)
    
    ' Populate the array (not relevant).
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
        For c = LBound(Data, 2) To UBound(Data, 2)
            Data(r, c) = r * c
        Next c
    Next r
    
    Sheet1.Cells.Clear
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = Sheet1.Range("A1")
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim rCount As Long
    Dim cCount As Long
    
    ' Wrong:
    Set drg = dCell.Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2))
    drg.Value = Data

    Dim msg As Long
    msg = MsgBox("This is wrong. Do you want to see the correct result?", _
        vbYesNo + vbExclamation, ProcName)
        
    If msg = vbYes Then
    
        drg.Clear
        
        ' Correct...
        rCount = rEnd - rStart + 1 ' it's not rEnd (Ubound(Data, 1))
        cCount = cEnd - cStart + 1 ' it's not cEnd (Ubound(Data, 2))
        ' ... i.e.:
        'Dim rCount As Long: rCount = UBound(Data, 1) - LBound(Data, 1) + 1
        'Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(Data, 2) - LBound(Data, 2) + 1
        Set drg = dCell.Resize(rCount, cCount)
        drg.Value = Data
    
        MsgBox "You are watching the correct result.", vbInformation, ProcName
    Else
        MsgBox "You are watching the wrong result.", vbInformation, ProcName
    End If

End Sub
```